# Unable to implement page factory in Karate Framework

Tags: java, appium, karate

I am trying to implement Page Factory concept in Karate Framework.

`LoginPage.java`

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='email-input']")
   public WebElement usernametxtbox;

@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='password-input']")
public WebElement passwordtxtbox;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }

    public void doLogin() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
       usernametxtbox.sendKeys("username");
      passwordtxtbox.sendKeys("password");
}
```

`Login.feature`

```
Background: App Preset
    * def LoginPage = Java.type('com.mobile.pages.LoginPage')
    * def LoginPageObj = new LoginPage(driver)

  Scenario: Android app UI test
    Given LoginPageObj.doLogin()
```

I am getting below error when I execute the above feature file

```
01: LoginPageObj.doLogin()
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Unsupported CSS selector '*[name='usernametxtbox']'. Reason: 'Error: 'name' is not a valid attribute. Supported attributes are 'checkable, checked, clickable, enabled, focusable, focused, long-clickable, scrollable, selected, index, instance, description, resource-id, text, class-name, package-name''
```

Karate is considering the WebElement name as the CSS selector when I try to do usernametxtbox.sendKeys("username");

Comment: sorry, I would not recommend using java at all in karate. please also read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#locator-lookup

Comment: Have you used this locator anywhere in your repository? `*[name='usernametxtbox']`